# Vbscript delay of 5 seconds

Tags: vbscript

I have two VBScripts. ScriptA calls ScriptB using the command below

```
C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe"" //Nologo //B ""C:\Program Files\ROC\ScriptB.vbs
```

From the ScriptA log file I can see at every run there is a delay of 5 seconds in starting ScriptB. Both scripts runs on Windows XP.

Is this a default behaviour? how can I change this?

Comment: It's not possible to tell what causes the delay from just the commandline that runs ScriptB. You need to provide the code from ScriptA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP won't add a delay to the start of the second script. There may be a delay if the system is under extremely heavy load, but doubtful with just a vbscript.

The best way to determine where your delay is coming from is to search through scriptA and see if you can find any `Sleep` methods being used. `Sleep` takes in an argument that tells it to pause for that many milliseconds, so you would pause for 5 seconds if you had a `Sleep(5000)` statement somewhere in your code.

If sleep is not being called, then most likely scriptA is just finishing up some code that doesn't log out to the log file before scriptB gets kicked off. If you want to determine the exact point of the delay, start at the point in scriptA where you call scriptB and add a two log statements that will print out the time to the log file. Slowly move the first log statement upwards away from the point where scriptB is called and you will be able to determine which code is taking 5 seconds to process before scriptB is started.